# How to log in to Centos 7 using RDP from Win10

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, centos

I am a bit frustrated now. I have configured our Centos 7 server to be accessible from windows remote desktop. The connection is ok, but the server is now in locked status and I can not wake it up. All I see is a nice blue screen with the clock and a notification from application installer. How can I send CTRL+ALT+DEL to make the login form appearing on the screen? Are there any other shortcut combinations for this?

[image: Centos 7 screen]

Comment: It should be like Windows where you left-click the mouse towards the bottom of the screen and drag up.

Comment: @n8te This works! Never used this before. Thank you! Ps. i think you should post it as answer not comment so I could accept as a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Gnome lockscreen behaves similar to the way you login to Windows 10.

To make the login screen appear to be able to unlock it, simply left-click your mouse towards the bottom of the screen and drag up.

Alternatively, you can also just start typing your password when you're looking at the lockscreen and it will automatically pull up the login screen behind it. Typing any alphanumeric/special-character keys causes the login screen to appear.

Comment: I noticed that you can do that with Linux Mint, but, didn't knew it works in other distros.

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer works <strike>around the issue</strike>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>end</kbd> will actually issue a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> on the remote, should you need it.
See [this](https://serverfault.com/a/57233/204068) for potential additional info.

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + Del actually doesn't even unlock a Gnome lockscreen, so Ctrl + Alt + End doesn't work in its place in a remote session. The link you provided is referring to a Windows system as the remote system they're RDP'd into.

Comment: @n8te ah okay. OP specifically asked about Ctrl + Alt + Del, that's why I figured it would actually unlock the lockscreen :)

Comment: Yeah, using Ctrl + Alt + End was my first thought too when reading OP's post. I had to fire up a linux VM to test it out.